# Maximum Expected Fishing Day (Recurrence Relation)

Tags: recurrence-relations, intuition, recursion

> John joined a meetup where organize day long fishing trip once a
>   month. The organizers are vary poor at planning, so will organize
>   fishing on a random day of the month without any advance notice.
>   Sadly, John needs to inform his boss in order to get time off from
>   work at least a day in advance. With this situation, John is forced to
>   schedule vacation days and hopping that the fishing will take place on
>   them. At the same time, he can be strategic about it. For instance, he
>   can wait until the end of the month at which point the fishing would
>   have already happened or will guarantee to occur the next day. John
>   can use a total of v  day of vacation for the next m months. What is
>   the greatest expected number of fishing meetup that he can arrange to
>   attend? For simplification, we can assume that a month is only 30 days
>   longs.
>
> It can be approached as: Defining the sub-problems as Maximum Expected
>   Fishing Days MEFD: for every situation MEFD(m,d,v), where m is the
>   number of months left including the current month, d is the numbers of
>   days left in the current one, and v is the number of vacation days
>   john left with the assumption that the fishing has not took place in
>   the current month.
>
> Base case: for any (m,d,v) such that i, j or l equals to 0,
>   MEFD(m,d,v) =0
>
> Recurrence Relation: MEFD(m,d,v) = max(MEFD$_{1}$(m,d,v), 
>   MEFD$_{2}$(m,d,v))
>
> MEFD$_{1}$(m,d,v)=$\frac{1}{d}$(1+MEFD(m-1,30,v-1))+
>   $\frac{d-1}{d}$MEFD(m-1,d-1,v),
>
> MEFD$_{2}$(m,d,v)=$\frac{1}{d}$(1+MEFD(m,30,v-1))+
>   $\frac{d-1}{d}$MEFD(m,d-1,v).

What does $\frac{1}{d}$ or $\frac{d-1}{d}$ means? Why do we need to multiply them ? Let's MEFD$_{1}$ means that the Maximum Expected Fishing Day that John takes a vacation day off in the next day. then it would fall into two cases: 1, fishing meetup take place, 2, it didn't take place. 
As we can tell from MEFD$_{1}$,  1 + ing means fishing meetup take place, then we - 1 from the months left and - 1 from vacations left.

What do we also need to -1 from months and vacations of the second part of the equation, + $\frac{d-1}{d}$MEFD(m-1,d-1,v)?

Or am i am reading this recurrence relation completely wrong? any points are really appreciated.

Comment: "Base case: for any $(m,d,v)$ such that $i, j \text{ or } l$ equals to $0,\ MEFD(m,d,v) =0$"  Is that supposed to be $m,d,\text{ or } v=0$?

Comment: I can't make sense of the recurrence relations either; please be sure you have copied them correctly.  The $1/d$ is the probability that the fishing trip happens today, and $(d-1)/d$ the probability that it doesn't.  In $MEFD_1$ the first term is the expectation if John scheduled vacation for today, but the second makes no sense.  In the first term, there are no more fishing trips this month, so we start over at next month.  In the second term, it makes no sense to subtract one from both the months and the days.  Surely, the months should stay the same. (cont.)

Comment: >  In the equation for $MEFD_2$ I have problems with the first term.  How can it be right for the month to stay the same but the days left to increase to $30$? Also, it seems like one formula should be for when John schedules a fishing trip the next day and one for when he doesn't, but then only one of them should have the possibility of getting a fishing day.  (The $1+$ in the first term.)